# How can I edit RSS feed address/URL in Apple Mail?

Tags: macos, email, url, rss

How can I easily edit / modify / change the address of an RSS feed URL / address in Apple Mail? I am on OS X 10.6.8, Mail 4.5.

I found information on how to use terminal to export the list of feeds, but is there a way to modify one? Or do I have to export the list to give me a record of what's there, delete the feed that needs changing, and then create a new feed, copy in the URL from the export, make the changes to it, and save it?

It seems like a very long winded process for something I thought would be super simple. Sometimes I wonder how Apple gets these simple things so horribly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written up a blog entry on that [here](http://best-mac-tips.com/2012/01/31/how-to-edit-or-retrieve-url-of-rss-feeds-in-apple-mail/).

#### If you are using OS X 10.6.x

(Snow Leopard, and perhaps earlier versions too)

Open the Terminal application.
Simply type “Terminal” into Spotlight quick search (Command-SPACE usually pulls up spotlight quick search). Not familiar with Terminal? Well, to be blunt, Terminal is one part of OSX the average user should never have to deal with at any time. Sadly, Apple doens’t always get its concepts straight, and we have to venture into things like Terminal. It’s basically a doorway into the underlaying UNIX framework of OSX. It’s like lifting the hood on your car to tinker with the motor.

Terminal looks like this:

[image]

In terminal type or copy/paste this command, and hit Return key:

```
for i in ~/Library/Mail/RSS/*/Info.plist; do defaults read "${i%.plist}" RSSFeedURLString; done
```

It will produce a nice list of the RSS feed URLs.

You can then copy and paste each of these into an application of your choice.

ALTERNATIVELY:

You can also paste this into terminal

```
pubsub --client com.apple.mail list
```

This will produce a list with RSS feed name and its URL. You will probably need to expand the Terminal window across the screen to prevent Terminal from line-wrapping the long feed details onto the next line (which makes them harder to read).

You can also use this in Terminal:

```
pubsub --client com.apple.mail list | cut -f3 | sed -ne '3,$p'
```

This will generate a list of the URLs like the first command I shared above.

#### If you are using OSX 10.7.x (Lion)

Follow the above instructions regarding Terminal, but paste in this command:

```
IFS=$'\n';for i in $(find ~/Library/Mail/V2/RSS/ -name "Info.plist");do grep "http://" $i | sed "s/.*\(http[^<]*\).*/\1/" >> ~/Desktop/Mail\ Feeds.txt;done
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome back! I took the liberty to add the actual post to your answer, since you own the rights on it anyway, and it's much easier to see the information here on site. I'll also inform a moderator to associate your accounts. Cheers.

Comment: Inspiredlife, I merged your old account into this new one for you. You should now be able to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks for coming back to update the post!

Comment: @slhkc: Thank you so much for doing that. It was late at night when I posted a link to my answer and I didn't feel motivated enough to try and figure out how to incorporate the full answer into a post on here. You've done it beautifully... pictures and all! Much appreciated.

Comment: @nhinkle - Thank you. I have no idea how I ended up with two accounts, nor how to reconcile them into one. I appreciate you merging them. Very helpful.

Comment: The for loop worked quite well for me, but I had to add a V2: "for i in ~/Library/Mail/V2/RSS/*/Info.plist; do defaults read "${i%.plist}" RSSFeedURLString; done"